# Integral of Modified Bessel Function of the second kind

Tags: integration

I'm trying to write a code to solve the below integral. But since K0 function cannot accept negative values I face an error. How this integral can be converted so it can be solved?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiFPx.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have obtained the antiderivative.

Now, for the definite integral, use the identity

$$K_n(-x)=(-1)^n \,K_n(x)-i\,\pi\, I_n(x)$$